# How to Test Facebook Login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I'd like to test the server-side manual login workflow I put together using the Facebook developer guide, but I'm unaware what options I have in this regard. At this point, the clients that will use service are yet to be created.

Does facebook or third parties offer a [login dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4#login) that can be used in such manual/automated (functional) tests? Or will I have to create a temporary client that calls the login dialog and handles the redirect myself?

Comment: There is already finished discussion on [stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/214154/how-can-i-unit-test-a-class-which-requires-a-web-service-call) for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook provides sandboxed test users (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users) that you can use for testing purposes.

If you are talking about writing automated tests around this, then consider using the test users along with something like vcr (https://github.com/vcr/vcr), or the equivalent for your server-side environment (you don't say what that is).

Comment: That’s super nice from fb to provide tests users, spot on answer.